# Secure form with single user password (without database)

Tags: php, regex, security

Many Question on StackOverflow about securing user/password form, securing administration section.

For this post I have created a Simple user password form.

I'm looking to use best practice and improve security this form..

Particularity:

- no database
- 1 user/password only
- 1 simple secure page

I know that we miss the Bruteforce system but without this feature,

(WITHOUT MYSQL or DATABASE)

** this example works

```
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["send"])):
    $username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';
    $password = isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:'';
    $username = strip_tags( trim( $username ));
    $password = strip_tags( trim( $password ));
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{4}$/i', $username) && $username=='user' && preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{8}$/i', $password) && $password=="password"):
        $_SESSION["login"] = 1;
    else:
        unset($_SESSION["login"]);
    endif;
endif;

if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || !$_SESSION['login']): 
?>
    <form class="login" action="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $a; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br>
        <button name="send"><span>Send</span></button>
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Win !</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm looking to use best practice and improve security this form.

Comment: Well you want to improve security? Make your password complicated, thats all you can do to be honest. You can try to implement pseudo bruteforce limiter, by saving failed attempts to session, and do not show form if count is higher than 3 i.e.

Comment: @MarkS sessions has nothing to do with bruteforce limiters, you know

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know, thats why I've said it is a pseudo security, just an idea without using db

Comment: @MarkS but it is not even "pseudo", it is no security at all. Anyway, with pretty good password no bruteforce would be a problem

Answer (score 0):

1) create a random string

2)Use `phpass library` to enrypt the data.Store it in an array.

https://phpbestpractices.org/#passwords

3) And while validating check if the encrypted password exists in the array.

**NOTE:** This is purely for the scenario tht u described although not recommended

Comment: it won't make the page more secure

Comment: Given his scenario this is wht i cud come up with

Comment: You are supposed to perform a sanity check for the scenario

Answer (score -1):

Just get rid of all the pointless stuff you put in

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == 'pass')
{
    $_SESSION["login"] = 1;
}
if(empty($_SESSION['login'])): 
?>
<form class="login" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <button name="send"><span>Send</span></button>
</form>
<?php exit; endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should tell him atleast what you did ..instead of pasting blatant code.